# Flutter - convert speech-to-text, then "translate" text by detecting and display the sign languages YouTube videos of the each words?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like to make an app that can convert speech-to-text from users, then click on a button to "translate" the text, and the text will be detected and the app will display the YouTube video which shows the sign languages of each words it detect. I am totally new in Flutter and NLP, can anyone help?

can someone provide guidance on how to make this app?